# How to reset a POSIX semaphore?

Tags: c++, semaphore

Maybe I am wrong but it seems to me that the semaphore [from this link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/semaphore.h.html) is missing a reset function.

Is there another way to reset its counter?
I found this implementation but does it really reset the semaphore?

```
void Semaphore::Reset()
{
    while(sem_trywait(&sem) == 0)
    {
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think you need this? Thinking you have a use for it at all tends to indicate that you may well be attempting to mis-use semaphores pretty badly.

Comment: I want to use the semaphore more like an auto reset event. The problem is that if "sem_post" is called before "sem_wait", then sem_wait will return immediately. I want to reset the semaphore and make sure that sem_wait will wait until the next sem_post. Is this possible?

Comment: You most likely want a condition variable instead of a semaphore.

Answer (score 0):

We keep reset the value of the semaphore to the initial value.

```
sem_getvalue(&sem, &value );
while(value > INITIAL_VAL  )
{
    sem_trywait(&sem);
    sem_getvalue(&sem, &value );
}
```

Disclamier: Untested code